# What does "$=" mean in jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the following code, what does **$=** mean? I tried Googling, but I'm not able to find any documentation.

```
$("a[href$='.png']").each(function {});
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: As you already have the answer to this one, [Take a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for a listing of this and other CSS3 attribute selectors available

Answer (score 1):

It means if the value of href attribute of anchor ends with `.png`.

[Attribute Ends With Selector [name$=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Select value end with ...

In your case, the whole selector means: select  elements with attribute 'href' is end with '.png'

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/